# Purpose of non-member functions like atomic_store()

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, lock-free

I read the documentation of [`atomic_store`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_store) and I understand what it is doing. The question is rather why is this non-member function there? What does it provide what member function doesn't? I mean member functions of `std::atomic` like [`std::atomic::store()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store)

There is also a bunch of such functions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

Comment: Memberfunction of what? `std::atomic`?

Comment: I believe it is in order to interface better with C11's `<stdatomic.h>`. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , yes, of course. I've edited the question.

Comment: @DeiDei, I don't see a way for them to interact with C without `reinterpret_cast`...

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the free functions is to provide an identical interface for atomics in C and C++. Atomics were developed in parallel between the C and C++ committees, which is why they are so similar (<g>). It's up to the implementor to make this work, but it's not hard if you start out with compatibility in mind. The result is that you can write the **same** code in C and in C++ if that's what you want, **or** you can take advantage of member functions in C++ to sometimes get simple and more powerful operations.